# .net core block specific BackgroundService if another one is already running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Having two different workers (BackgroundService) in .net core 3.1 worker service project:

```
services.AddHostedService<MainTaskWorker>();
services.AddHostedService<SideTaskWorker>();
```

Is it possible to block `SideTaskWorker` if `MainTaskWorker` is running?

Worker implementation (simplified) - same for `Main` and `Side`:

```
public class SideTaskWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<SideTaskWorker> _logger;

    public SideTaskWorker(ILogger<SideTaskWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("SideTask running at: {time}", DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
    }
}
```

Additional info:

`MainTask` - runs every day, needs minutes/hours to finish

`SideTask` - runs every 15min, needs few seconds/minutes to finish

`SideTaskWorker` and `MainTaskWorker` are two different classes with different implementation of `ExecuteAsync` method. The issue is that both workers are modifying same database tables and I don't want to touch the tables with `SideTask` when `MainTask` is currently running.

`SideTask` is not business critical and can be blocked for minutes/hours/days. data in db tables shouldn't be changed as `MainTask`'s one of functionality is to generate a report based on data in db

Comment: You should provide more information on how and when you want to block the `BackgroundService`.

Comment: Do you only want to prevent data collision when these methods try to access your table at the same time?

Comment: need to prevent that data will be changed when main task is running. the data shouldnt be changed by `SideTask` when `MainTask` is running.

Comment: So I guess from your question it is not that important if the code won't get executed in the `SideTask` for multiple times in a row?

Comment: yes, `SideTask` is not business critical and can be blocked for minutes/hours/days. data in db tables shouldn't be changed as `MainTask`'s one of functionality is to generate a report based on data in db

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your methods are doing exactly and under which circumstances you want to block the `SideTaskWorker` exactly. Also I'll assume that you want to *block* your `ExecuteAsync` method.

You should take a look at [`SimpaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-2.2).

Not sure if it actually fits your needs, but in your case I would create a bool which would indicate if you want to *block* the `SideTaskWorker` method. Assuming that other work happens in the `SideTaskWorker` method you would need to check if the bool is changed to `true` and if this is the case you should call `await semaphore.WaitAsync();` and as soon as you want to let the `SideTaskWorker` continue call `semaphore.Release();`. Additionally you should set your bool back to `false`.

Note that this can get very dirty especially with DI in ASP.Net Core. You might want to create your own handler and take a look at [`Semaphore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netcore-2.2) which you can give name.

Comment: updated question with additional info - it's not clear for me how to use it in my case because the workers are two different classes without any dependencies between each other (they are just in same assembly)